# illegal start of expression in multi threading (java)

Tags: java, multithreading

Basically i run this code on netbeans it works, on atom it doesnt for me... any advice, downloaded atoms as i want to code java with a compiler but i do not want something complicated, similar to brackets...

problem:

```
public class multithreading {

    public static void execute(final String name)
    {

        for(int index=1; index<=5; index++)
        {

            System.out.println("thread " + name + " - " + index);

        }

    }


    public static void main(String []args){

       final Thread one = new Thread(() -> execute("first Thread"));
       final Thread two = new Thread(() -> execute("second Thread"));
       final Thread three = new Thread(() -> execute("third Thread"));

       one.start();
       two.start();
       three.start();

    }

}
```

errors:

```
multithreading.java:18: error: illegal start of expression
       final Thread one = new Thread(() -> execute("first Thread"));
                                      ^

multithreading.java:18: error: illegal start of expression
       final Thread one = new Thread(() -> execute("first Thread"));
                                         ^

multithreading.java:19: error: illegal start of expression
       final Thread two = new Thread(() -> execute("second Thread"));
                                      ^

multithreading.java:19: error: illegal start of expression
       final Thread two = new Thread(() -> execute("second Thread"));
                                         ^

multithreading.java:20: error: illegal start of expression
       final Thread three = new Thread(() -> execute("third Thread"));
                                        ^

multithreading.java:20: error: illegal start of expression
       final Thread three = new Thread(() -> execute("third Thread"));
                                           ^

6 errors [Finished in 0.226s]
```

Comment: what version of java does atom run?

Comment: Try to run java -version ?? ...are you using java 8

Answer (score 1):

Must be an older Java version you are trying to run this on. Lambda's like `() -> execute("first Thread")` are only available since Java 8.